# Dealing with References & Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, reference, nuget, nuget-package

I am having a bit of trouble. I have no idea what question title is appropiate in this case, feel free to edit it, if you have something better in mind.

**So, basically this is the current situation:**

Currently I have four projects (not the real names, but the architecture is identical):

1. `Client` (the main client logic)
2. `Server.Main` (the main server logic)
3. `Server.Extensions` (some functions for the server, e.g. helpers etc. can be used standalone, shouldn't rely on something from Server.Main)
4. `Shared` (shared code between client & server)

For each of the projects I create a Nuget-Package and upload it to my online repository. This repository is private for now and only for development purposes.

**Here is a summary, what project uses what Nuget-packages:**

1. `Client` uses the Nuget Package of `Shared`.
2. `Server.Main` uses the Nuget Package of `Shared` & `Server Extensions`.
3. `Server.Extensions` uses the Nuget Package of `Shared`.

This works fine for me at the moment... I can easily update my repository for testing purposes and use the freshly updated version of my package.

**But here comes the problem:**

I would like to share my project with other people now (e.g. the GitHub community). But when they have gotten the projects, they don't have any access to my private repository and the nuget package manager will not find the packages.

Further more there is another problem with my architecture: When they will fix something, e.g. in `Shared`, they wouldn't be able to test the changes, because the `Client` & `Server` would always use the Nuget package from the repository and not the fixed/changed local code.

And I thought about referencing the `Shared` project directly in all other three projects. Would that mean, that whenever I update `Shared`, I have update all other three projects aswell?

I think, my whole Nuget architecture is wrong. But I don't know how to do it correctly / in any better way. Does anyone have a better approach for me?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this is necessarily wrong. If someone is trying to consume and work on your solution, P2P (project to project) references are probably the best since there is minimum overhead and there is a higher probability of catching issues early on during build and subsequent debugging sessions.

You can still easily create NuGet packages for all three during build and consume them in lets say a integration test by either packing them in a post build step or using tools like [NuProj](http://nuproj.net/).

Comment: Thank you :) I just figured out, how to reference other nuget packages inside a nuget package. I was always using a PostBuild script for it which did it automatically, but I will try to start with building them manually with Nuget Package Explorer. That way, I hopefully will be able to delete all the nuget stuff from my source code, so I can upload it to github one day. :)